# How to make Xpath for button “li” elements of “ul” in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium webdriver. Can someone help me how to make Xpath for (Flag button) on below code.

```html
<div class="right-pan">
<ul class="right-pan-btn">
<li class="closeandtrain">
<a class="gray-color" onclick="btnChangeReviewStatusClick(3)">
<span class="statusiconclass icon-close1"/>
Close
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="btnChangeReviewStatusClick('3_1')" title="Close and train this policy">
<span class="icon-hats"/>
Close
</a>
</li>
<li class="noclassName">
<a onclick="btnChangeReviewStatusClick(4)">
<span class="flag"/>
Flag
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="btnChangeReviewStatusClick(5)">
<span class="esc"/>
Escalate
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a onclick="btnCaseClick()">
<span class="case"/>
Case
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<ul class="right-pan-links">
</div>
```

I tried it on Fire path that path is not working and its showing (Unable to locate element) exception

Comment: Which path you have tried?

Comment: Flag path <li class="noclassName">
<a onclick="btnChangeReviewStatusClick(4)">
<span class="flag"/>
Flag
</a>
</li>

Comment: This is not xpath actually

Comment: Please read about Xpaths.

Comment: Ok how do make path (button click) for this flag,I need to click the flag button, i tried this one dr.findElement(By.xpath("[contains(@class,'flag')]")).click(); not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try xpath //span[@class='flag']

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to comment to your post, so posting this as answer.
You can go through this link to learn about xpaths.
http://www.tizag.com/xmlTutorial/xpathtutorial.php

Comment: Ok how do make path (button click) for this flag,I need to click the flag button, I tried this one dr.findElement(By.xpath("[contains(@class,'flag')]")).click(); not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this
I think you should click parent of span

//span[@class='flag' and text()='Flag']/ancestor::a[1]

or

//span[@class='flag' and text()='Flag']/..